# Rating control in windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, rating-system

I have seen a rating control in JavaScript/HTML Project for windows 8 . BUt I couldn't see anything like that in XAML yet . :(

Any idea how to achieve rating control in windows 8 ?..

Seems like Microsoft treating XAML guys as second guys :(...

Comment: Have you tried creating one yourself? What were the problems you encountered?

Comment: I am trying to create one user control right now. because  of I am newbie to xaml and most of the samples got from net not work in metro, everything going wrong

Comment: You could try to port rating control from Silverlight Toolkit. I ported TransitioningContentControl successfully, so it shouldn't be too hard. Or you could wait till Metro XAML Toolkit is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ported an open source control for displaying ratings with stars from WPF.

Maybe you can start from there, or find it useful.

http://igrali.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/show-ratings-with-stars-in-winrt-xaml/

http://metrorate.codeplex.com/

Comment: It is not working... No matter the value is.. but the color of stars does not change

Comment: It's been written and tested for the preview version of the Windows... You might want to check the code and the discussions on CodePlex for some edits...

Comment: @bendewey that's been answered on May 2012, while Windows 8 was in preview, and it worked then. I said that in the comments.

Answer (score 12):

There is also a ratings control in Callisto

https://github.com/timheuer/Callisto

Example code that shows 3 our of 5 stars lit up:

```
<callisto:Rating
    Value="3" ItemCount="5"
    Background="Transparent" Foreground="Gold" />
```

Comment: How to get the start number in c# when i use callisto package.And is there a way to give rating to decimal levels also. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[App promo](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Improve-app-ratings-with-a-6139caa5) project is good for user ratings in Windows/WP. I was searching for more than a day and now I am happy to use and share app promo.

Regarding App promo : App Promo is a tiny control library for Windows Phone and Windows 8. It has a RateReminder control to solve rating problems.

**Links** :

1. [App promo - code.msdn.microsoft.com](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Improve-app-ratings-with-a-6139caa5)
2. [App promo - Source code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Improve-app-ratings-with-a-6139caa5/view/SourceCode#content)